# NetBeans8 Java Maven application and rebuilding local dependencies

Tags: java, netbeans

I created two Java applications:
- Web project
- Common code (DAO, Models, etc)

I added an "Open Projects" dependency - Common code - to the Web project.

Up to this point everything works well. The problem is when I chance something in the common code. I would expect my changes to by automatically uploaded to the Web Project as soon as I "Build with Dependencies" it. Unfortunately that's not the case. 
The only way to refresh the "Common code" dependency which worked for me was to remove it from the project and add it again.

I'm expecting to change the common code quite often so re-adding dependency is not the ideal approach. Is to possible to set my project in a way that it will get the latest version of common code on every build?

Comment: What about a **clean build**? For understanding: you alter common code, build it and a new jar is put into your local maven reposition (probably the same SNAPSHOT version). Maven still has the same version in the project target dir, and does not update from the repository. Clean should do.

Comment: Strange thing. After your comment I went back to NetBeans and everything worked perfectly well. Any change done to project1 was immediately available in project2. I didn't have to clean or build anything. Perhaps I came across a bug or did something silly.

Comment: Cache timeout? Sometimes the magic of what is really happening can be tiring.